# Comparar elementos de un arreglo de numeros enteros

Tags: java, array

Necesito comparar en un array si el numero que se digito esta repetido si es asi tire mensaje numero esta repetido e ingresar uno nuevo,

```
    int i, n;

    n = Integer.parseInt(
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null," Digite la cantidad de campos para el vector "));

    int Vect1[] = new int[n];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                    Vect1[i] = Integer.parseInt(
         JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
         "Digite el valor del vector  en la posicion " +
         "[" + i + "]" ));
    }
```

ya lo he intenado de varias maneras pero el IF solo funcina si especifico el campo Vect1[0] Vect1[1],

Comment: define ingresar de nuevo

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema no es difícil, con la ayuda de algunos `if` y el uso de `for` podrías haberlo resuelto fácilmente. He dado un poco de cabeza yo mismo para ayudarte y lo he resuelto rápidamente.

Solución:

```
int n;

n = Integer.parseInt(
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null," Digite la cantidad de campos para el vector "));

int Vect1[] = new int[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        Vect1[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite el valor del vector en la posición " + "[" + i + "]" ));

        // Si "i" es diferente de 0 ya que no habrá ningún valor con que compararlo
        if (i != 0) {
            // comparar el valor digitado con el valor de todas las posiciones existentes del array
            for(int z = 0; z < i; z++) {
                if (Vect1[i] == Vect1[z]) { // si encuentra uno repetido entra aquí
                    // preguntar por un valor nuevo
                    Vect1[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Número repetido, digite otro valor del vector en la posición " + "[" + i + "]" ));
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Lo he probado muy deprisa y funciona bien, si llegas a encontrar algún error, de seguro podrás solucionarlo. Tu problema era de pensar un poco detenidamente, nada del otro mundo.

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos!.

Comment: Esta respuesta tiene un fallo (al menos uno se ve a primera vista). Si pides un número y está ya repetido, te lo vuelve a pedir, pero si lo vuelves a meter repetido va mal. Si está repetido, podrías indicarlo, decrementar uno a i y volver al inicio del for, así lo vuelves a pedir y a comprobar si está o no tantas veces como sea (no se si me he explicado bien o no...)

Answer (score 0):

Este es el algoritmo de un ejercicio similar al de la pregunta, el cual pide calcular la moda de "N" notas, en el código puedes apreciar el código de comparación.

```
int n[],a,b=0,cont=0,I=0;

a=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"> Ingrese el número de notas "));
n=new int[a];

for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    n[i]=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"> Ingrese la Nota: [ "+i+" ]"));
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (n[i]==n[j]) {
            I=n[i];
            cont++;
        }
    }
}

if (cont<=a) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"> Moda: "+I);
}else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"> No hay moda");
```

Answer (score -1):

Hola aquí esta mi solución orientada a objetos.
Primero creamos este método

```
  boolean comparar(int vector[],int posicionFinal,int numero){ // Bueno este es un metodo que nos servira para hacer el recorrido del vector hasta la posicion en donde nos encontremos para evitar problemas de null pointer
    for(int i=0;i<posicionFinal;i++){
        if(vector[i]==numero){ //hacemos una comparacion para saber si el numero ingresado ya se ha repetido, si es asi retornamos un true ya que pues la comparacion dio verdadero
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false; // si al final del ciclo no se encontro ninguna coincidencia en el numero pues retornamos un false ya que la comparacion dio falso
}
```

Después creamos el método donde se ejecutara el proceso

```
 public void proceso() {
    int tamaño;
    int i; 
    int numero;
    boolean primero = true; //variable para saber si estamos en la primera casilla del arreglo
    boolean repetido;
    tamaño = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el tamaño del vector")); // Determina el tamaño del vector
    int vector[] = new int[tamaño];

    for(i=0;i<tamaño;i++){
        if(!primero){ // preguntamos si no es la primera posicion del arrelo para asi evitarnos una iteracion de mas en la comparacion
            numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite un numero")); // pedimos el ingreso del numero
            repetido = comparar(vector,i,numero); // le metemos a nuestra variable "repetido" lo que contenga el resultado de comparar el numero con nuestro metodo
            while(repetido==true){ // ahora haremos un ciclo mientras que repetido sea igual a verdadero osea mientras el usuario siga agregando numeros existentes pues le pediremos que ingrese uno nuevo
                numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Numero "+numero+" repetido, escriba otro numero")); // le notificamos al usuario que el numero ya esta repetido y que ingrese otro
                repetido = comparar(vector,i,numero);//volvemos a comparar ahora con el nuevo numero que ingreso el usuario arribita
            }
            vector[i] = numero; // si el numero no esta repetido pues lo asignamos a la casilla del vector correspondiente
        }else{ // si estamos en la primera posicion del vector simplemente agregamos el numero a la casilla 0.
            numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite un numero"));
            vector[i] = numero;
            primero = false;
        }
    }
    //imprimimos el vector resultante
     for(i=0;i<tamaño;i++){
         System.out.println(vector[i]);
     }

}
```

Finalmente creamos una instancia de la clase y llamamos al método "proceso".

```
 public static  void main(String args[]){
    Soverflow ejemplo = new Soverflow();
    ejemplo.proceso();
}
```

Incluso se podría hacer recursivamente pero eso ya es otra historia, espero te sirva y saludos.